# Linq slowness materializing complex queries

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework, nhibernate

I have often found that if I have too many joins in a Linq query (whether using Entity Framework or NHibernate) and/or the shape of the resulting anonymous class is too complex, Linq takes a very long time to materialize the result set into objects.

This is a generic question, but here's a specific example using NHibernate:

```
var libraryBookIdsWithShelfAndBookTagQuery = (from shelf in session.Query<Shelf>()
    join sbttref in session.Query<ShelfBookTagTypeCrossReference>() on
         shelf.ShelfId equals sbttref.ShelfId
    join bookTag in session.Query<BookTag>() on
         sbttref.BookTagTypeId equals (byte)bookTag.BookTagType
    join btbref in session.Query<BookTagBookCrossReference>() on
         bookTag.BookTagId equals btbref.BookTagId
    join book in session.Query<Book>() on
         btbref.BookId equals book.BookId
    join libraryBook in session.Query<LibraryBook>() on
         book.BookId equals libraryBook.BookId
    join library in session.Query<LibraryCredential>() on
         libraryBook.LibraryCredentialId equals library.LibraryCredentialId
    join lcsg in session
         .Query<LibraryCredentialSalesforceGroupCrossReference>()
          on library.LibraryCredentialId equals lcsg.LibraryCredentialId
    join userGroup in session.Query<UserGroup>() on
         lcsg.UserGroupOrganizationId equals userGroup.UserGroupOrganizationId
    where
         shelf.ShelfId == shelfId &&
         userGroup.UserGroupId == userGroupId &&
         !book.IsDeleted &&
         book.IsDrm != null &&
         book.BookFormatTypeId != null
    select new
    {
        Book = book,
        LibraryBook = libraryBook,
        BookTag = bookTag
    });

// add a couple of where clauses, then...
var result = libraryBookIdsWithShelfAndBookTagQuery.ToList();
```

I know it's not the query execution, because I put a sniffer on the database and I can see that the query is taking 0ms, yet the code is taking about a second to execute that query and bring back all of 11 records.

So yeah, this is an overly complex query, having 8 joins between 9 tables, and I could probably restructure it into several smaller queries.  Or I could turn it into a stored procedure - but would that help?

What I'm trying to understand is, where is that red line crossed between a query that is performant and one that starts to struggle with materialization?  What's going on under the hood?  And would it help if this were a SP whose flat results I subsequently manipulate in memory into the right shape?

**EDIT:** in response to a request in the comments, here's the SQL emitted:

```
SELECT DISTINCT book4_.bookid                 AS BookId12_0_, 
                libraryboo5_.librarybookid    AS LibraryB1_35_1_, 
                booktag2_.booktagid           AS BookTagId15_2_, 
                book4_.title                  AS Title12_0_, 
                book4_.isbn                   AS ISBN12_0_, 
                book4_.publicationdate        AS Publicat4_12_0_, 
                book4_.classificationtypeid   AS Classifi5_12_0_, 
                book4_.synopsis               AS Synopsis12_0_, 
                book4_.thumbnailurl           AS Thumbnai7_12_0_, 
                book4_.retinathumbnailurl     AS RetinaTh8_12_0_, 
                book4_.totalpages             AS TotalPages12_0_, 
                book4_.lastpage               AS LastPage12_0_, 
                book4_.lastpagelocation       AS LastPag11_12_0_, 
                book4_.lexilerating           AS LexileR12_12_0_, 
                book4_.lastpageposition       AS LastPag13_12_0_, 
                book4_.hidden                 AS Hidden12_0_, 
                book4_.teacherhidden          AS Teacher15_12_0_, 
                book4_.modifieddatetime       AS Modifie16_12_0_, 
                book4_.isdeleted              AS IsDeleted12_0_, 
                book4_.importedwithlexile     AS Importe18_12_0_, 
                book4_.bookformattypeid       AS BookFor19_12_0_, 
                book4_.isdrm                  AS IsDrm12_0_, 
                book4_.lightsailready         AS LightSa21_12_0_, 
                libraryboo5_.bookid           AS BookId35_1_, 
                libraryboo5_.libraryid        AS LibraryId35_1_, 
                libraryboo5_.externalid       AS ExternalId35_1_, 
                libraryboo5_.totalcopies      AS TotalCop5_35_1_, 
                libraryboo5_.availablecopies  AS Availabl6_35_1_, 
                libraryboo5_.statuschangedate AS StatusCh7_35_1_, 
                booktag2_.booktagtypeid       AS BookTagT2_15_2_, 
                booktag2_.booktagvalue        AS BookTagV3_15_2_ 
FROM   shelf shelf0_, 
       shelfbooktagtypecrossreference shelfbookt1_, 
       booktag booktag2_, 
       booktagbookcrossreference booktagboo3_, 
       book book4_, 
       librarybook libraryboo5_, 
       library librarycre6_, 
       librarycredentialsalesforcegroupcrossreference librarycre7_, 
       usergroup usergroup8_ 
WHERE  shelfbookt1_.shelfid = shelf0_.shelfid 
       AND booktag2_.booktagtypeid = shelfbookt1_.booktagtypeid 
       AND booktagboo3_.booktagid = booktag2_.booktagid 
       AND book4_.bookid = booktagboo3_.bookid 
       AND libraryboo5_.bookid = book4_.bookid 
       AND librarycre6_.libraryid = libraryboo5_.libraryid 
       AND librarycre7_.librarycredentialid = librarycre6_.libraryid 
       AND usergroup8_.usergrouporganizationid = 
           librarycre7_.usergrouporganizationid 
       AND shelf0_.shelfid = @p0 
       AND usergroup8_.usergroupid = @p1 
       AND NOT ( book4_.isdeleted = 1 ) 
       AND ( book4_.isdrm IS NOT NULL ) 
       AND ( book4_.bookformattypeid IS NOT NULL ) 
       AND book4_.lightsailready = 1
```

**EDIT 2:** Here's the performance analysis from ANTS Performance Profiler:

[image: Performance analysis by ANTS]

Comment: How much results you will get if "// add a couple of where clauses, then..." part is omitted?

Comment: @VitaliyKalinin, um... more?  But why is that relevant?

Comment: This is an interesting question. Can you show us the SQL that gets generated? Have you tried performing the same query using NHibernate's QueryOver syntax?

Comment: @AndrewShepherd I've added the sql to the question.  I don't see why it would make a difference, though; the query itself executes in negligible time.  Haven't tried QueryOver; why do you think it would make a difference?

Comment: @AndrewShepherd thanks for the formatting :)

Comment: How much more? I suspect that where clause applied after projection maybe actually done either inefficiently or in worst case totally on client side. From SQL code it looks like we are dealing here with worst case, i.e. additional filtering is applied on client side.

Comment: Another point which may affect materialization is how many navigation property you have defined in model and whether they support eager or lazy loading.

Comment: @VitaliyKalinin The query is 100% server side.  Trust me on this.  I get to the breakpoint in the debugger, then execute that one line of code, which fires the query and loads everything into memory. About lazy loading: in point of fact, and much to my disgust, the entities are defined without any navigation properties at all (hence all the joins on `session.Query<Blah>` rather than using navigation properties).  But it does at least preclude the possibility of lazy loading being involved here.

Comment: Do you have a performance tool (like dotTrace) that you can use to profile the Linq query execution?  I would try one to look for the hotspots and see where the execution time is being spent.  Some of these tools have free trials if you don't already have one.

Comment: Also, if you execute the sql query that EF is emitting directly against the database, how many rows does it return?  Is the number abnormally high?

Comment: @TyreeJackson See my latest edit.  The performance problems are clearly not from SQL.  And it's returning 11 rows.

Comment: @ShaulBehr Based on what I'm reading in your update, it would appear that the CreateQuery method is taking the bulk of the execution time.  Can you get a precise timing measurement from ANTS in milliseconds laid out in a call tree with framework method calls included?

Comment: @ShaulBehr I think you can see the major time consumption on query creation might be better go for view and get object from view or you can try [compiled query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896297(v=vs.100).aspx) and also can disable [proxy generation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx#6) if you required read only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is often database "good" practice to place lots of joins or super common joins into views. ORMs don't let you ignore these facts nor do they supplement the decades of time spent fine tuning databases to do these kinds of things efficiently. Refactor those joins into a singular view or a couple views if that'd make more sense in the greater perspective of your application.

NHibernate should be optimizing the query down and reducing the data so that .Net only has to mess with the important parts. However, if those domain objects are just naturally large, that's still a lot of data. Also, if it's a really large result set in terms of rows returned, that's a lot of objects getting instantiated even if the DB is able to return the set quickly. Refactoring this query into a view that only returns the data you actually need would also reduce object instantiation overhead.

Another thought would be to not do a `.ToList()`. Return the enumerable and let your code lazily consume the data.

Comment: I've worked with LINQ and EF in exclusively massive data SQL sets and while it does sometimes introduce unnecessary overhead if you're not explicit, most of the slowdown you'll experience will be client-side, not SQL side. I would add, though, that if you're creating views, do not -DO. NOT- let them be used by anything else. I've had to wade through complex views drawing on complex views ad-infinitum, and that *will* slow SQL to a crawl.

Comment: My question is one of principle: most of my queries work fine, and you don't even feel a bump with the materialization.  But then you cross a line somewhere, and the materialization starts adding a real cost to the query.  Why?  And why would it help to change from a Linq query with 8 joins, to a SP or view with no joins?  It's still the same flat data being massaged into the same anonymous class result set.

Comment: @ShaulBehr You haven't given enough detail to get a detailed answer. What does `Book` look like, for instance? Does it have any navigation properties? What about the others? Are there any circular reference issues?

To be fair, I'm not 100% on the internals of NHibernate like I am with EF so if this next part doesn't make sense then so be it. You're still asking the cache mechanism to load up and do matching between a lot of types of objects and then synthesize a composite. ORMs bread and butter categorically is the meta-information about how things relate so they can do their job.

Comment: By popular vote I'm giving you the bounty.  The actual solution was for us to refactor the query only to return the minimum number of columns.

Comment: That's what I figured and why I recommended the view because of all your joins. I'm glad you worked it out!

Answer (score 3):

According to profiling information, the `CreateQuery` takes 45% of the total execution time. However as you mentioned the query took 0ms when you executed directly. But this alone is not enough to say there is a performance problem because,

1. You are running the query with the profiler which has significant impact on execution time.
2. When you use a profiler, it will affect every code is being profiled but not the sql execution time (because it happens in the SQL server), so you can see everything else is slower compared to SQL statement.

so ideal scenario is to measure how long it takes to execute entire code block, measure time for SQL query and calculate times, and if you do that you will probably end up with different values.

However, I'm not saying that the the NH Linq to SQL implementation is optimized for any query you come up with, but there are other ways in NHibernate to deal with those situations such as QueryOverAPI, CriteriaQueries, HQL and finally SQL.

1. > Where is that red line crossed between a query that is performant and
   >   one that starts to struggle with materialization. What's going on under the hood?

This one is pretty hard question and without having detail knowledge of NHibernate Linq to SQL provider it's hard to provide a accurate answer. You can always try different mechanisms provided and see which one is the best for given scenario.

2. > And would it help if this were a SP whose flat results I subsequently
   >   manipulate in memory into the right shape?

Yes, using a SP would help things to work pretty fast, but using SP would add more maintenance problems to your code base.

Answer (score 2):

You have generic question, I'll tell you generic answer :)

1. If you query data for reading (not for update) try to use anonymous classes. The reason is - they are lighter to create, they have no navigatoin properties. And you select only data you need! It's very important rule. So, try to replace your select with smth like this:

   `select new
   {
       Book = new { book.Id, book.Name},
       LibraryBook = new { libraryBook.Id, libraryBook.AnotherProperty},
       BookTag = new { bookTag.Name}
   }`
2. Stored procedures are good, when query is complex and linq-provider generates not effective code, so, you can replace it with plain SQL or stored procedure. It's not offten case and, I think, it's not your situation
3. Run your sql-query. How many rows it returns? Is it the same value as result? Sometimes linq provider generates code, that select much more rows to select one entity. It happens, when entity has one to many relationship with another selecting entity. For example:

`class Book
{
    int Id {get;set;}
    string Name {get;set;}
    ICollection<Tag> Tags {get;set;}
}
class Tag
{
    string Name {get;set;}
    Book Book {get;set;}
}
...
dbContext.Books.Where(o => o.Id == 1).Select(o=>new {Book = o, Tags = o.Tags}).Single();`
I Select only one book with Id = 1, but provider will generate code, that returns rows amount equals to Tags amount (entity framework does this).

4. Split complex query to set of simple and join in client side. Sometimes, you have complex query with many conditionals and resulting sql become terrible. So, you split you big query to more simple, get results of each and join/filter on client side.

At the end, I advice you to use anonymous class as result of select.

Answer (score 2):

[Don’t use Linq’s Join. Navigate!](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/)

in that post you can see:

> As long as there are proper foreign key constraints in the database, the navigation properties will be created automatically. It is also possible to manually add them in the ORM designer. As with all LINQ to SQL usage I think that it is best to focus on getting the database right and have the code exactly reflect the database structure. With the relations properly specified as foreign keys the code can safely make assumptions about referential integrity between the tables.

Comment: I'm 100% in agreement with this.  And we do want to start moving in this direction (though it may take some time and a new release cycle).  But do you think it would enhance performance?

Comment: it might have some optimization according to your DB structures.

Answer (score 0):

I agree 100% with the sentiments expressed by everyone else (with regards to their being two parts to the optimisation here and the SQL execution being a big unknown, and likely cause of poor performance).

Another part of the solution that might help you get some speed is to pre-compile your LINQ statements. I remember this being a huge optimisation on a tiny project  (high traffic) I worked on ages and ages ago... seems like it would contribute to the client side slowness you're seeing. Having said all that though I've not found a need to use them since... so heed everyone else's warnings first! :)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896297(v=vs.100).aspx